# how to add Constraint in loop using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

While using "addConstraint" on UIButton in loop issue is coming with button x-position,

```
for (int ix = 0; ix<7; ix++) {

        UIButton *segmentButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [segmentButton setTitle:[_segmentButtonTitleArray objectAtIndex:ix] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_segmentView addSubview:segmentButton];

            [segmentButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

            [_segmentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentButton
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:_segmentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                 multiplier:1.0/7
                                                                   constant:0]];
            [_segmentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentButton
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:nil
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:segmentButton.frame.size.height]];

            [_segmentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentButton
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:_segmentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:segmentButtonXposition]];

            [_segmentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:segmentButton
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:_segmentView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:segmentButton.layer.frame.origin.y]];

        segmentButtonXposition = segmentButtonXposition +1+_segmentView.frame.size.width/7-1;
    }
```

An the desired result is like that, but unable to produce result.

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bewjn.png)

Comment: What result are you getting? Could you post an image of what is being produced?

Comment: hi @GavinHope have already posted the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/bewjn.png . Getting the result once loaded. But after rotation it's taking previous width

Comment: Oh, so the initial load produces the result you want, but if you rotate the device, you get the wrong width? To be specific, if you rotate from **portrait** to **landscape**, does the landscape orientation keep the *width* that was used in portrait?

Comment: the immediate parent view is taking device width, that's why initial loading is working fine for portrait or landscape. Once i rotate from portrait to landscape all the view rotating against the view but only this section is not working - please check the image http://i.stack.imgur.com/26dnQ.png

Answer (score 0):

It sure will take the previous width after rotation. See how you are calculating the `left` attribute value for constraint; from `segmentVIew's` frame, which you are not updating after the rotation.

So if we say that for portrait orientation your computation comes as `768/7 = ~109`. However for Landscape orientation this calculation is not correct and `constraint.constant` value should be updated with `1024/7 = ~146`. But you are not doing that, so an old value is being taken.

To resolve this, you can update each constraint every time device makes a rotation. But that is going to be tedious as you need to have a variable for each constraint and then iterate through all of them.

A better approach is to keep the equal width constraint to each UILabel with each other.

> 1. EqualWidth for each lable
> 2. label1.leading = segmentView.leading
> 3. label7.trainling = segmentView.trailing
> 4. label(n).trailing = label(n+1).leading

For reference check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991500/uiscrollview-add-subview-horizontally-pure-autolayout-with-for-loop/33992126#33992126). Through it is applied in `UIScrollView` but it will help you understand this logic. And i have used VFL for that which is lot more concise.